# Libshout-2.3.1 make error

Tags: gcc, makefile, libtool

I am trying to build libshout from source in Linux and am coming across an error that I can't seem to solve. My ./configure command runs without error but when I run make I get the following error:

```
/usr/bin/sed: can't read =/usr/lib/libogg.la: No such file or directory
libtool: link: `=/usr/lib/libogg.la' is not a valid libtool archive
make[3]: *** [libshout.la] Error 1
```

That extra '=' in front of the libogg path name does not show up if I try to build the source on another Linux machine. I cannot figure out why the '=' is there. My only suspicion is that the compilers are different. On the machine that is not working:

```
gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 4.5.3 20110311 (prerelease)
```

On the machine that is working:

```
gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3
```

Libogg.la does exist in /usr/lib so all I need to do is figure out how to get rid of the '='. I have tried older versions of libshout with the same results. Has anyone seen anything similar to this and come across a solution? Thanks in advance.

Comment: gcc 4.5.3 is pretty old. It was release 2011-04-28. Current gcc is 4.7.

Comment: Are you 100% sure you got the `./configure` line correct and that you don't have funky env. vars?

Comment: 100% positive. I just re-checked the ./configure output and config.log and it was able to find libogg. I also checked the generated libtool file and none of the variables had any extra characters floating around. I also checked the env vars and there isn't anything extraneous that should affect the compilation. I've sifted through some of the autogenerated Makefiles and it almost seems as if a regex is being interpreted differently between the two systems. Maybe that's a bash problem? I will experiment with that now.

Comment: I have updated bash and have received the same results. Now I am stuck. I was attempting to not have to update GCC but that may be where my problem is. Any more ideas are greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: @rob.tice see, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1664921/debian-dropped-support-for-la-files-how-do-i-build-now

Comment: Thanks for the link but that is a different problem. I came across that post before posting this and tried to bypass the libtool grabbing the full path without any success. I am not sure why the libtool is getting the string "=/usr/lib/libogg.la" as the location of the file.